# Style rule based on feature adjacent edges and ignore vertices

Tags: qgis, geometry, style, overlay, adjacency

I have a set of square tiles which I want to show in a different colour when the tile to the north, south east & west are present in the same way as below with the links I want in black.

[image: Example online tile viewer]

I have been using `array_length (overlay_intersects(@layer, $id)` to give me a count of the number of adjacent tiles however this is counting all adjacent tiles including ones which only touch by a single vertex and so it counts polygons which are diagonally adjacent, those with the green arrows. Is there a way to exclude these?

Comment: You could use array_filter and check if the provided feature has an edge that is equal to the current feature, or more than a single vertex (this is assuming everything is square and snapped.).